# Drawing phase planes

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to draw the phase plane of Y'=$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        -3 &  1 \\
        1 & -3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$Y
The general solution of the system was,
Y(t)=C$_1$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
          1 \\
        1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$e$^{-2t}$+C$_2$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
          1 \\
        -1  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$e$^{-4t}$
I know how to get the direction of the trajectories(plug a point to the equation y= Y'=AY).But I don't understand to which direction these trajectories **bend**.This gives a improper node.
In the class the lecturer considered separate cases when c$_1$=0 ,c$_2$=+/-1 and c$_2$=0,c$_1$=+/-1.
I don't understand how the direction to which these trajectories bend was decided with this .Any help on how I can decide on the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can look at the eigenvalues.
- You can also look at the derivative in the different quadrants where
  we have:

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx}  = \dfrac{-3x+y}{x-3y}$$

- You can draw the solution curves using various initial conditions. In your approach, we have $c_1 = 0, c_2 = \pm 1$. We could, for example, parametrically plot $x(t) = e^{-4t}, ~y(t) = -e^{-4t}$ to see how the trajectory looks for various values of $t$. We see (the direction arrow is pointing in toward the origin):

[image]

You can also see: [Difference between improper node and proper node for phase portrait](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235208/difference-between-improper-node-and-proper-node-for-phase-portrait)

Since both eigenvalues are negative and real, this is an asymptotically stable node. We have the critical point at $(0,0)$.

This leads to the phase portrait:

[image]

Comment: I know how to determine the type of critical point and also whether it is stable or not by looking at eigen values.And also I know how to get the direction of(whether it is coming towards(0,0) or moves away).My problem is when drawing phase portraits by hand,In this example If I consider the first quadrant of x,y plane and if I draw y=x line, how to determine whether the trajectories between y axis and y=x, curve towards y=x or toward y axis as t increases.

Comment: That was the note I provided regarding the parametric plot. We have $x(t)$ and $y(t)$. Do you know how to plot $x$ versus $y$ parametrically?

Comment: No.How to look at the derivative at each quadrant

Comment: That was my second bullet. Are you not following that? You have an expression for the derivative $\frac{dy}{dx}$. Plug in positive values of $x$ and $y$ for the first quadrant, draw the derivative direction and magnitude arrows (those are green in my figure) and what does the derivative give you for those values?

Comment: 1st and 3rd quadrants have positive derivatives and the other two are negative.In 1st quadrant though it has a positive derivative trajectory can bend towards y axis or towards x axis,having at each time a positive derivative

Comment: That is correct. Now look at one additional thing, we have as a numerator in $dy/dx$, $-3x + y$. What happens at $y=3x$ to the derivative? Can you see how we have what appears to be that weird looking line affect line through the origin? It takes a little time to get used to these and they are sort of a qualitative analysis. Regards

Comment: At y=3x,derivative is 0.So that means points along that line should have a derivative parallel to the x axis.That is when the tangent lines change direction.When y=x/3 the gradient is infinity. Well I don't understand this.Thanks a lot for the help